WhatsApp Business API: Template message not received despite successful API response
I'm encountering an issue with the WhatsApp Business API where template messages are not being received, despite getting a successful API response.
Issue: When sending an approved template message via the WhatsApp Business API, I receive a 200 success response, but the message is not delivered to the recipient's WhatsApp. However, normal text messages are received successfully.
Environment:

Using WhatsApp Business API

Sending messages via Postman

Have necessary token and phone number ID

Phone number registered and connected in Meta Business Manager

Message template approved


Template Message Payload:
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "917xxxxxxxx",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "billz_order",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_US"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "₹500.00"
          },
          {
            "type": "date_time",
            "date_time": {
              "fallback_value": "October 25, 2023"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

API Response for Template Message:
{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "contacts": [ { "input": "91xxxxxxxxx", "wa_id": "917339249430" } ], "messages": [ { "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE3MzM5MjQ5NDMwFQIAERgSMkRERkFBRTRFRjNEMjA2RkM5AA==", "message_status": "accepted" } ] }
Test Message Payload (which works):
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "911234567890",
  "type": "text",
  "text": {
    "body": "This is a test message. Hello from WhatsApp API!"
  }
}

Despite the message being accepted, it’s not delivered to the recipient. What could be the reasons for this, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

Verified that the template is approved in the Meta Business Manager

Confirmed that the phone number is correctly registered and connected

Checked that the token and phone number ID are correct

Ensured that the template payload matches the approved template structure




have you got anything related to this in webhook ?

I only receive data from the webhook when I send a test message, but not when I send a template message. I have a doubt: do I need to add a payment method to send a template message?

payment method is required to add , as it is a last step of embedded sign-up.
